# What's the best tablet for my needs?

Tags: tablet

My notebook stopped working and, seen that I mainly use it as a desktop computer, I'd rather buy a desktop computer this time.

This leaves me with the need to buy a tablet, that will be used for the following tasks:

- Reading PDF files. The task involves continuonusly switching between different pages (views) and files, without hyperlinks.
- Showing pictures to people.
- Browsing the Internet, in wi-fi covered areas (and possibly on a stand). Mom will probably browse recipes while cooking, I hope she won't smear the poor thing with food.
- Writing in sites like this one.
- Use my desktop PC through some app.

The only one that is really necessary is the first one, most others I can do at the desktop PC if necessary. As a consequence, I have been suggested to aim for at least 10" and good resolution.
Note how I don't need a camera or phone connectivity and I don't care much about weight or to how the device looks.

I would like to spend as low as I can without sacrificing durability.

The device will be used at home mainly, so a battery that does not degrade over time is better than a battery that lasts a lot for each single charge (and then, power banks to the rescue if it needs be).

The item must be available for sale via Internet, from a reliable supplier (I consider Amazon to be reliable).

---

Feel free to ask me for more details if needed.

Comment: "Use my desktop PC through some app." Would Teamviewer work?

Comment: For physical keyboard: is Bluetooth fine, or would you want wired? If so, is a wire poking out the side fine, or do you want a seamless connection? Given that almost every tablet uses a glossy screen, would an aftermarket matte screen protector work?

Comment: @JMY1000 No keyboard is fine, I can use the desktop PC if I need to write, after all. I will use a matte screen if I see that being glossy really is a problem. I think teamwiever is fine, anyway it's a low priority requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR: The All New Fire HD 10.

Since price seems to be a major concern for you, I'm going to sacrifice in it's name. However, I think this should still pass quite fine for what you're doing, if not excellent.

With the Fire, some cons are:

- Low res screen (only 1920x1200 for a 10.1" device = 224.17 PPI, about 85% of an iPad Pro 10.5" and about 48% of an iPhone X)
- Fairly low storage capacity
- No cellular capability
- Very slightly slow (roughly 75% of the Apple A10X Fusion in the most recent iPad Pro, only 2GB of memory)
- Runs Fire OS, and getting "normal" Android things (like the Google Play store) is [very possible, but takes a bit of extra work.](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-get-google-play-on-a-kindle-fire-and-install-any-1790706649)

Besides that though, it's actually a surprisingly good device. It has an IPS display, proper dual band AC wireless solution, Bluetooth, a microSD slot (a real rarity these days) to mitigate the storage issue, a surprisingly good battery, is very rugged, and **costs a mere $150** for the 32GB model, basically creaming anything at that price point and size. Compared especially to the old Fire HD 10, it's amazing.

Going over your requirements briefly then:

- Reading PDF files: Yes. It's a Kindle. If there's one thing it can do, it's read books.
- Showing pictures to people: Yes, though your app of choice may not be available without a little extra effort.
- Browsing the Internet: Yes, and has a pretty good wireless solution to boot
- Use a desktop PC remotely: Yes; I recommend [TeamViewer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006LRUVUA), which is available on the Amazon store as well (free!)
- 10" screen: Yes
- Resolution: Not awful, but not great
- Cheap price: Yes, incredibly.
- Durability: Yes, it's actually market heavily as a durable tablet.
- Battery: It's going to degrade as much as any other lithium-ion (they're all basically the same), but it should do a solid 8-10 hours on a charge. It also won't throttle when the battery begins to degrade too much (looking at you, Apple.)
- Reputable retailer: It's literally an Amazon product.
- Physical keyboard: Yes, either with the (rather expensive) [$60 official flush keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KYFWDLU) or any generic Bluetooth keyboard.
- Anti-reflective screen: Very few devices use matte screens these days, your best bet is a matte screen protector. They're available on the extremely cheap (from Amazon as well.

Comment: I have a single critique on all this: most e-readers I know use e-ink and e-ink is B/W only AFAIK. Reading books (which is what I'd expect a Kindle to do) and reading PDFs in general look like a different thing to me ;)

Comment: @Zachiel Missing how that's a critique; it's got a good IPS LCD, so PDFs should be fine. It's "just another Android tablet." To be fair, the real advantage of E Ink is really battery life only though, and there's no reason you can't read books as well on an LCD display, and by extension, this tablet. There are [tri-color E Ink displays](http://www.eink.com/color-technology.html), but Amazon doesn't even bother making a Kindle with one.

Comment: Well I just wanted to point out (but I'm probably being pedantic here, and you're in no way required to change your answer) that "being a kindle" does not automatically mean it can read all books, since some books are in color and not all kindles can show color, e.g. mono-color e-ink. Nothing to worry about, and thanks for your research effort!

Comment: True, but they're purpose built for it, so they'll generally be pretty good at it. If you like the answer, if you'd like, go ahead and vote up; if this satisfies what you're looking for, go accept it.

Comment: I waited for a bit to see if other votes came in but I guess it is time to cast mine and accept.

Answer (score 0):

As all these kind of questions...there is no 1+1 answer...and honestly any 10", $150 and up, tablet should be good enough.

But for really good resolution and adequate battery size, I'd suggest one of the 2 (depending on how much you're willing to shell out):

1. The [**ASUS ZenPad 3S 10 9.7"**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MATMXZV) for $284
2. The (flagship) [**Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 9.7"**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MTGLBP5) for somewhat below $500